# created micropost with t.text :content, results in unpermitted parameter "text"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created a basic devise login with microposts which have :user_id from :users, and t.text :content. If it matters I generated this with a scaffold content:text.  Here is the micropost controller:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @micropost = Micropost.new
  end

  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.create(params[:content])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @micropost.save!
        format.html { redirect_to microposts_path, notice: 'Micropost was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @micropost }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @micropost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def micropost_params
    params.require(:micropost).permit( :content)
  end
end
```

However everytime I try and create/save a 'micropost' is results in 'unpermitted parameter:text'?  Any help is appreciated.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: micropost, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if micropost.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(micropost.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this micropost from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% micropost.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
     </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
   <%= f.text_field :text %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What's the payload of your post?

Comment: I would assume the limit for a :text column in :content row, t.text :content in table, like "Hello, my name is..., bye." You mean - Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TfrayOR1gwsLJEm/X3b/CHOSONlPDJD6sVr/re6gn5FIfn5mOi0pgUO5HoiBx0H24+X/cOiJtMq3rqufMy8ZQQ==", "micropost"=>{"text"=>"Hello, my name is...bye."}, "commit"=>"Create Micropost"} ?  Or, @micropost.create(params[:content])?

Comment: No I mean send me the actual body of your http post request.

Comment: Can you show the form?

Comment: You have defined `micropost_params`, but using less secure `params[:micropost]` in `create` action. Why?

Comment: I was frustrated and changed the @micropost.create with params[:content], trying make sure it grabbed params, but will change it back.  I've posted the form too.

Comment: Sorry!  I just realized I was useing :text in the form_with instead of :content!  My mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field in your form is `text` but your fields name is `content`.  Change the text field in your form to `:content`.

Answer (score 0):

This was just laziness on my part, the micropost new.html.erb had no form.label or form.text_are, additionally @micropost = Micropost.create was typed wrong as @micropost.create.  Sorry guys!